# Insertar registro en tabla por cada registro del resultado de una consulta

Tags: sql-server, insert

Dada una tabla con artículos, querría, en otra tabla(stock)insertar un valor por cada registro de la tabla artículos con su stock(aleatorio).
Pero algo estoy haciendo mal, ya que solo recibo errores ¿me podéis guiar en que estoy haciendo mal por favor?

```
  insert into StockInternet(CodigoEmpresa,CodigoArticulo,Unidades,CodigoAlmacen)
  VALUES
            ('1',
            SELECT a.CodigoArticulo,
            FLOOR(RAND()*(99-1)+1),
            'INET'
            FROM Articulos as A
            Where a.PublicarInternet='1')
```

Ya sé que no tiene ningún sentido insertar stock aleatorio, es solo para pruebas.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesaria la sentencia `VALUES`, realizas un `SELECT` de los datos a insertar después del `INSERT INTO`, y es suficiente.

```
  insert into StockInternet(CodigoEmpresa,CodigoArticulo,Unidades,CodigoAlmacen)
  SELECT '1', a.CodigoArticulo, FLOOR(RAND()*(99-1)+1), 'INET'
  FROM Articulos as A
  Where a.PublicarInternet='1'
```

Para solucionar el problema del RAND, deberás combinar diferentes funciones, en este caso con `CHECKSUM()` y `NEWID()`

```
  insert into StockInternet(CodigoEmpresa,CodigoArticulo,Unidades,CodigoAlmacen)
  SELECT '1', a.CodigoArticulo, FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(99-1)+1), 'INET'
  FROM Articulos as A
  Where a.PublicarInternet='1'
```

Comment: Vaya, muchas gracias, ahora el problema lo tengo con en RAND, ya que para todos los registros es el mismo valor.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para cubrir la problemática del `RAND()`

Comment: Lo había resuelto de forma similar:
`CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 AS INT)`
Pero me parece mas elegante tu solución.
Gracias.